# sinon.js withArgs callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, tdd, stub, sinon

I'd like to test that a certain function gets called in a certain way, in my server-side javascript. I'm using Sinon mocks and stubs. Sinon has withArgs() method, to check that a function got called with certain arguments. Is it possible to use that method, withArgs(), if I pass a large complex callback function as one of the arguments?

```
var foo = function(){ method: function () {}};
// use: foo.method(function(){ console.log('something') } );
var spy = sinon.spy(foo, 'method');
spy.withArgs( ??? );
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example is a little confusing, because you've defined `foo` as a function, but the comment that follows calls `foo.method()`:

```
var foo = function(){ method: function () {}};
// use: foo.method(function(){ console.log('something') } );
```

In any case, a "large complex callback function" is just an object.  `withArgs` returns a spy object that is filtered by the given args, and you can use a function as part of that filter.  For example:

```
var arg1 = function () { /* large, complex function here :) */ };
var arg2 = function() {};
var foo = {
    method: function () {}
};
var spy = sinon.spy(foo, 'method');
foo.method(arg1);
foo.method(arg2);
console.assert(spy.calledTwice);  // passes
console.assert(spy.withArgs(arg1).calledOnce); // passes
console.assert(spy.withArgs(arg1).calledWith(arg1));  // passes
console.assert(spy.withArgs(arg1).calledWith(arg2));  // fails, as expected
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vtw2p/)

Comment: See, I'd perefer to not use the complex function in the tests.

Comment: Can you use a spy or a stub instead?

Comment: JavaScript, being dynamic, the way I currently go about it is by stubbing. Without using sinon.js or any other framework - I just rewrite the complex callback to do the minimal functionality and set some internal testing flags. So, my current solution is outside sinon.js.